# Pull from 2 tables to gather results of only matching items

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my SQL panel. I have one that appears like this

This one is called games:

```
ID | Game | Season
 1   MKX2     3
 2   GMR      4
 3   GH4      3
```

Then I have one for users signed up for a game called game_stats:

```
ID | User    | GID | Season | Points
 1   Jordan     1      2        10
 2   Jordan     1      3        15
 3   Jordan     3      3        25
 4   Grape      2      1        16
 5   Grape      2      4        17
```

How can I pull a user's most recent game_stats for the current season? So let's say I want to grab all of Jordan's most reason Game stats. However, I want to only grab the rows that match the game's season. So for example, If I grabbed Jordan I'd want these rows:

```
ID | User    | GID | Season | Points
 2   Jordan     1      3        15
 3   Jordan     3      3        25
```

So, ID 1 from game_stats is left out because there was no season matching the number "2" on the original games table. This would give me his current season if he is signed up for it.

How can I combine tables to do this?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Comment: `MYSQL` or `MSSQL` ?

Comment: Sorry, I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.USER,
       a.GID,
       a.Season,
       a.Points
FROM   game_stats a
       JOIN games b
         ON a.GID = b.ID
            AND a.Season = b.m_season
```

or you can use `Exists`

```
SELECT ID,
       USER,
       GID,
       Season,
       Points
FROM   game_stats a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   game_stats b
               WHERE  a.GID = b.ID
                      AND a.Season = b.m_season)
```

Comment: Where do you pull the information from the table games to verify the season? Also, which one do people think is more efficient?

Comment: This worked great, thank you very much. The inner join was easier for me.